# Is BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME fine to use in Android app to get App version

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I needed to use get my app's Version when it launches so I used `VERSION_NAME` from `BuildConfig` which works but **Is it the right way to get the Version Name of app?**

I found that if the app's build folder is removed `BuildConfig` becomes an undefined or unimported class thus we need to Make Project Again from Build Menu to resolve this issue.

### Shall I try other Options to fetch Version Name or `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` will be fine?

#### Works when Build Folder is Available (As Expected)

[image]

[image]

#### Without Build Folder / After Deleting Build Folder

Not Working Until Project is Rebuild and Build Folder is recreated
[image]

Comment: Yes `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME ` is totally fine. If you don't find `BuildConfig.java`, you have rebuild project from menu `Build` -> `Rebuild`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi, This is Correct way to get the Version_name, and by way you can also get version code also from same method, so this is correct, what exactly happens is,
Gradle allows buildConfigField lines to define constants. These constants will be accessible at runtime as static fields of the BuildConfig class. This can be used to create flavors by defining all fields within the defaultConfig block, then overriding them for individual build flavors as needed.

ALSO alternatively you can have a code something like this,

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;//Version Name
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;//Version Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This to Get The Version Name

**Extension Function**

```kotlin
fun Context.getPackageInfo(): PackageInfo {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(0))
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
    }
}
```

#### Fragment

```
binding.tvBuildVersion.text = requireContext().getPackageInfo().versionName
```

#### Activity

```
binding.tvBuildVersion.text = getPackageInfo().versionName
```